# how to make a selected input box/image more highlighted?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a quick way to make a selected inputbox, image, dropdown box more highlighted when a user is focused on it?

Currently on a input box you get a light yellow box in chrome around it, i want it to be more visible so maybe a thicker yellow box or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need jQuery for this:

```
<style>
:focus { outline: solid red }
</style>
```

The beauty of `outline` is that it (unlike `border`) does not change the layout of the page when it is added or removed; it stays on top of the content.

If you need to support old browsers in this respect, then you need more complicated code.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery for `input` elements:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','#FF0000'); // red background color
});
```

For selectboxes: `$('select').focus(function(){`

For images: `$('img').focus(function(){`

If you want to change the border instead of background color, just change `backgroundColor` into `border`. Or any other CSS property you want to change of course. Also look at the [jQuery CSS documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/).

And use the `.blur()` function to change it back.

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','none'); // no background color
});
```

Using `input` as selector, this lines will work for all input boxes.

Comment: erm that makes all the text boxes red, not just the highlighted one?

Comment: @Beginner pardon me, fixed with `this`

Comment: dropdown boxes/select boxes & images are not input fields, I'll change the answer including how to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourInoutId").focus(function() {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid yellow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

how about `style="border:solid 3px red"`

```
$(this).css("border", "solid 3px red");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the focus psuedo class in css for achieving this. [Check this](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/focus_pseudo_class/)

there is another example for using jquery here

[Check this](http://css-tricks.com/improved-current-field-highlighting-in-forms/)